# Unit testing AngularJS routes throwing Error: Unexpected request

Tags: unit-testing, angularjs, karma-runner

Below is my Jasmine RoutesSpec.js

```
describe("Todo Routes", function(){
    var route;
    var rootScope;
    var location;

    beforeEach(function(){
        module('todoApp');

        inject(function($route, $location, $rootScope){
            route = $route;
            location = $location;
            rootScope = $rootScope;
        }); 
    });

    it("should navigate to todo list", function(){
        expect(route.current).toBeUndefined();
        location.path('/todos');
        rootScope.$digest();
        expect(route.current.templateUrl).toBe('app/html/listTodos.html');
    });
});
```

Below is my app.js

```
var todoModule = angular.module("todoApp", []);

todoModule.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.when('/todos', {
        templateUrl: '../html/listTodos.html',
        controller: 'TodoListController'
    })
    .otherwise({redirectTo: '/todos'});
});

todoModule.controller("TodoListController", function($scope, $log){
    $scope.todos = [{title: "My first task", done: false}];
    $log.log('In list controller');
});
```

Executing this spec throws me the below error:

> Error: Unexpected request: GET ../html/listTodos.html
>           No more request expected
>               at Error ()
>               at $httpBackend (C:/Learn/Javascript/todo_app/libs/angular-mocks.js:934:9)
>               at sendReq (C:/Learn/Javascript/todo_app/libs/angular.js:9146:9)
>               at $http (C:/Learn/Javascript/todo_app/libs/angular.js:8937:17)
>               at Function.$http.(anonymous function) (C:/Learn/Javascript/todo_app/libs/angular.js:9080:18)
>               at $q.when.then.then.next.locals (C:/Learn/Javascript/todo_app/libs/angular.js:7440:34)
>               at wrappedCallback (C:/Learn/Javascript/todo_app/libs/angular.js:6846:59)
>               at wrappedCallback (C:/Learn/Javascript/todo_app/libs/angular.js:6846:59)
>               at C:/Learn/Javascript/todo_app/libs/angular.js:6883:26
>               at Object.Scope.$eval (C:/Learn/Javascript/todo_app/libs/angular.js:8057:28)

Comment: Setting the root to /todos in your test triggers the http loading of the partial associated to this route. But since you haven't mocked the httpBackend to tell it what to do when receiving a request for this partial, you get this error.

Comment: Does that mean, the solution provided by Juho here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15990102/angularjs-route-unit-testing would also not work?

Comment: Don't know. Not an expert in angular. I'm just analyzing the error you got.

Answer (score 2):

This means that there is an AJAX call that goes to fetch the template.
$httpBackend.expectGET('app/html/listTodos.html').respond(200) can be put before calling path():

```
describe("Todo Routes", function(){
    var route;
    var rootScope;
    var location;
    var httpBackend;

    beforeEach(function(){
        module('todoApp');

        inject(function($route, $location, $rootScope, $httpBackend){
            route = $route;
            location = $location;
            rootScope = $rootScope;
            httpBackend = $httpBackend;
        }); 
    });

    it("should navigate to todo list", function(){
        httpBackend.expectGET('app/html/listTodos.html').respond(200);//mimicking the AJAX call
        expect(route.current).toBeUndefined();
        location.path('/todos');
        rootScope.$digest();
        expect(route.current.templateUrl).toBe('app/html/listTodos.html');
    });
});
```