# TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'angular.module ) using ngRoute

Tags: javascript, angularjs, karma-jasmine, ngroute

I dont know if its a valid question but as long as i inject ngRoute into my app 
my $scope is undefined.

the app without ng-Route looks like this

```
angular.module('DummyApp', [])
.controller('DummyCtrl', ['$scope',  function ($scope) {
    $scope.name = "World";
}]);
```

the test case like this

```
describe( 'Dummy Controller', function(){
    var scope, http, DummyCtrl;

    beforeEach(module('DummyApp'));
    beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $rootScope) {

        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        DummyCtrl = $controller('DummyCtrl', {
            $scope: scope
        });
    }));

    it('should contain the word world', function(){
        expect(scope.name).toEqual("World");
    });

});
```

**passing without any error**

but if i inject the ngRoute to my app

```
angular.module('DummyApp', ['ngRoute'])
.controller('DummyCtrl', ['$scope',  function ($scope) {
    $scope.name = "World";
}]);
```

TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'scope.name')

---

I also tried to configure the $routeProvider see below
but i just don't know how to write my test if the ngRoute is injected

```
angular.module('DummyApp', ['ngRoute']).app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
    when('/smth', {
        templateUrl: 'smth.html',
        controller: 'testController'
    });
}])
.controller('DummyCtrl', ['$scope',  function ($scope) {
    $scope.name = "World";
}]);
```

Comment: Did you include all required js files in your test environment or karma config? i.e. angular-route.js

Comment: I have spent days on this nothing makes sense as long as i include the ngRoute my  $scope is lost,

Comment: in your karma.config, looks like your 'node_modules/angular-route' is only pointing to the directory.

Comment: files: [ 'node_modules/angular/angular.js', 'node_modules/angular-route.js', 'node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js', 'app/public/**/*.js', 'test/**/*.js' ]

Comment: no i checked it and it has the .js

Comment: do you mind create a plunker so I can help you better?

Comment: I have tried till this time but i cant recreate it in plunket , there is no karma -jasmine package, and i have no idea how to use this site

Comment: also there is no angular-mocks package

Comment: you have an additional 'app' on this line angular.module('DummyApp', ['ngRoute']).app.config. This must be a copy and paste issue. it should be angular.module('DummyApp', ['ngRoute']).config

Comment: i manage the plunker [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/eJZYNpguaKGln4UIaZRk?p=preview)

Comment: my last comment should have solved your problem...

Comment: why do you need to inject $routeProvider in your test?

Comment: if you want to test your route config, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17963717/can-we-write-unit-test-for-angularjs-routeprovider

Comment: thanks but i manage to make it work, it was the angular and angular-route was a different version .

Comment: no problem. I guess the first question I should ask should be: - what version are you using. hehe