# Should resolved objects be tested in routes unit test in Angular?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-runner, angularjs-routing

Currently in routes unit test I'm testing if appropriate controller and template are called, like seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17976106/1864751). 
Also, in some routes I have resolved object. I can access them like:

```
expect($route.routes['/someroute'].resolve.name_of_field).not.toBe(null);
```

My question is: Should I check for resolved objects in routes unit test because they are part of routing config on one hand but on the other should I cover that by unit testing services that are used for resolving objects?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is better to have separate unit test for resolving objects.

Answer (score 0):

When unit testing related components, you should think of each of them as having a specific "job", and you want to test that it does that job, e.g. controller's job can be "receive data, pass them to the $scope/ViewModel", service's job "provide data", and the router's job "given an url, resolve data from the correct service and pass them to the correct controller".

So to answer your question: when testing routes that have resolves, you should mock the services that provide them, and verify that the correct controller gets called with the mocked resolve from the service.