# Angular js routing unit testing

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner

I am new to angular js and trying to unit testing on ngRoute, But Getting this error :
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'location.path').

Here is my code for Unit testing

describe('Testing angularJS Test Suite', function() {

```
var location, route, rootScope;
beforeEach(module('myApp'));

beforeEach(inject(
function( _$location_, _$route_, _$rootScope_ ) {
    location = _$location_;
    route = _$route_;
    rootScope = _$rootScope_;
}));


describe('Registration route', function() {
    beforeEach(inject(
        function($httpBackend) {
            $httpBackend.expectGET('views/registration.html')
            .respond(200);
        }));

    it('should load the registration page on successful load of /registration', function() {
        location.path('/registration');
        rootScope.$digest();
        expect(route.current.controller).toBe('RegistrationController')
    });
```

});
})

Can anyone suggest me, Why I am getting this error.
Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [angularjs route unit testing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15990102/angularjs-route-unit-testing)

Comment: use $state.go('registration') (assuming 'registration' is your state's name)